# Resizing div beyond the end of the screen (vertical)

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there was a way to make the div, upon resize, extend PAST the vertical screen size? 
The div resizes (somewhat) but it will not resize beyond the screen.

My current way of resizing that div (the parchment-coloured box) is:

```
div.mainBack{
   position:absolute;
   display:inline-block;
   top:50%;
   right:5%;
   transform:translate(0, -50%);
   border-style:outset;
   border-color:#B57F00;
   border-width:5px;
   background-color:#FCDD92;    /*  PARCHMENT - kind of*/
} 

div.mainWrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:3%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    max-width:90%;
}

#imgWrapper{
    position:relative;
    padding-left:12%;
}
```

The body for the page I'm talking about is as follows:

```
<body>
<h1 id="pageHead">The Astantos Armoury</h1>
<p id="subhead">A Simple Introduction to Bladed Weaponry</p>

/* The images have a "href" because I have simple javascript that makes an
image gallery i.e. when you click the image you get a full size version */
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="mainWrapper">
        <p id="galleryHeading">Image Gallery</p>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="mainWrapper" id="imgWrapper">
        <img class="gallery" 
            src="images\sword_thumb.jpg" 
            href="images\sword.jpg" 
            data-caption="wallpaper-gallery.net/single/sword-wallpaper/sword-wallpaper-9.html" 
            alt="dao.jpg">
        <img class="gallery" 
            src="images\dao_thumb.jpg" 
            href="images\dao.jpg" 
            data-caption="https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Top-quality-of-Ba-Gua-Dao-Wushu-BroadSwords-with-free-shipping/32439115049.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.111.gVLuZw" 
            alt="dao.jpg">
        <img class="gallery" 
            src="images\guandao_thumb.jpg" 
            href="images\guandao.jpg" 
            data-caption="https://aliexpress.com/item/Damasucs-Steel-Kwan-Dao-Dadao-Guan-Gong-Dao-Master-Dao-Heavy-Duty/32612836207.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.22.j1tTli" 
            alt="guandao.jpg">
            <img class="gallery" 
                src="images\jian_thumb.jpg" 
                href="images\jian.jpg" 
                data-caption="https://au.pinterest.com/pin/325385141814676112/" 
                alt="jian.jpg">
        <img class="gallery" 
                src="images\spear_thumb.jpg" 
                href="images\spear.jpg" 
                data-caption="http://kung-fu-weapons.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/sp3-3.jpg" 
                alt="spear.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mainWrapper" id="homeButton"><a href="home.html"><p id="welcome">HOME</p></a></div>
</div>
```

I've attached images to clarify my point.
[image: At full screen]
[image: On a smaller screen, when images start shifting]

Comment: Hi, you need to post the complete html and reproduce the problem here in your post. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I thought I gave enough info because it's (i thought) just a css thing. 
I have now included the entire <body> of that page